# How to fix this Login button error in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, authentication, netbeans

Tried to make a login using Netbeans IDE and when I use this code for the login button always it shows "User name or password is incorrect"although the correct username and password is given. How to fix it?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String un =jTextField1.getText();
        char[] pass =jPasswordField1.getPassword();

        if(un.equals("admin") && pass.equals("123"))
                {
                 MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
                 mf.setVisible(true);
                 mf.pack();
                 mf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                 mf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                 this.dispose();

                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Successfully Logged in as the Admin","info",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                 }

            else {  
                jTextField1.setText("");
                jPasswordField1.setText("");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"User name or password is incorrect","info",JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                 }

    }
```

Comment: So you store your Password as a Char and then you compare your Char with a String by using equals("123")??? Looks wrong to me. You will never get a successful login like that.

Comment: Cast your Char to String or compare Char with Char and not Char with String "123". Should fix your Problem.

Comment: `String pass = String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword());`